Is a router's DNS cache shared among all users?
Following a recent question about router DNS caches, I am wondering something else:

Let’s say Bob and Alice share a LAN whose router has local DNS caching.

Bob visits a new domain, which gets resolved by a DNS provider, and stored in the router’s cache.

Now if Alice later visits that same domain, will she get to use Bob’s earlier information in the cache?


So in other words, is a router’s DNS cache shared among all users, or only for each individual user?

This depends on whether Alice's device is set to resolve DNS from the router or from elsewhere on the internet. This is likely (but not certain) to depend on the router configuration as it will in general hand out the DNS server addresses by DHCP.

I would also wonder if this is dependent on whether the router is set to assign each client a private sub-net. For example, when I've stayed at hotels, I've seen that each client is generally invisible to other patrons. It would not surprise me if the cache is not shared under such a configuration.

@SoronelHaetir I would be surprised if it wasn't (if there is a cache at all). Also in many cases each client does not get an actual dedicated subnet (i.e. with non-overlapping IP network ranges), but there's just "client separation", which means there is no communication possible between clients, only between clients and router and from there to the Internet (and back). No broadcast, no direct client-to-client communication, no client-to-client communication via the router either.

I don't know if you are headed  in this direction, but given that your, OP's,  username is "security paranoid":   Yes,  if a router is DNS cache is shared, as is typical, then  it can be used as a covert timing channel.   Any shared resource is a covert channel.  e.g. Reference: Kaminsky, D. "Covert Channels Using DNS." Presentation at Black Hat USA, 2004.  (RIP DK, we miss you.)

@KrazyGlew well actually, being a security researcher, yes, a potential attack scenario I originally considered with this was DNS poisoning through manually choosing what a domain resolves to (e.g. your malicious server of choice,) and then the router redirecting everyone there from the cache. However I don't think this is plausible because this probably wouldn't even reach the router's cache, instead you'd probably only be poisoning your own browser cache.

There are lots of papers in the literature on DNS poisoning, DNS covert channels, and other DNS security issues.

Being able to share the cache between multiple clients in the network is the main reason that there is a DNS cache at all in the home router.

Note that it's generally not possible to poison the DNS cache on the router in such way that Bob request poisons the cache, while Alice's request (if done earlier) wouldn't. DNS cache on the router means that the router acts as a DNS server for the clients (broadcasting its address via DHCP option 6). When a client requests a domain name to be resolved, it first asks the router, and  then the router performs a DNS request to another server if the address is not found in the cache. The clients do not provide resolved IP addresses for the router.

(In other words, typically Bob needs to exploit a vulnerability on the router to manipulate its cache, or find a way to spoof the "external" DNS used to populate the router's cache)

@Bergi I'd say the main reason in a home network is the ability to do local DNS records, particularly before mDNS became common for IoT devices. Some home ISPs would prefer you didn't cache at all because they want to do analytics/advertising based on your lookups.

@user71659 In theory you could add local records and not have a cache for forwarded requests, but of course once you implement a DNS server it'll have a cache.

There's only a single DNS cache on routers and DNS servers, so it's ultimately shared between users/clients.
There may be exceptions to this but I have yet to see one.

Cheers. Then if there is only one then it must be shared.

This is not entirely true, given that DNS entries can expire based upon TTL values.

@LPChip I don’t understand how this is relevant. If a resolver updates its cached record due to one expiring, it still gives the same result to all users. Lots of comments on this Q trying to give clever answers about private subnets etc to what is fundamentally a simple question which this post answers simply and accurately.

@Darren Why that is true 90% of the time, it is not always the case. If you manage a domain on the internet, you changed the A record, and the router still has the old value cached, once the TTL expires, the new A record will be fetched from the public DNS server. If that public DNS server still has the old value cached, you get the old value again, but google DNS servers may already have the new record (or the other way around), and you get different results, especially if you had the TTL set to 1 day and changed it to 5 minutes. So yes, the TTL is very relevant here depending on the usecase.

@LPChip Cache entry expiration doesn't really matter that much here - whether a single user queries the same record within a certain time period or there are multiple users doing that, the cache works the exact same way.

@Zac67 of course, that is what cache means. But if the TTL expires, the entry is removed from cache, and a new entry is fetched on the next query, which could be different. My point is that sometimes people don't want the cached entries and are worried that cache is happening, other times people want it cached, but its not. TTL thus matters, and my point is solely to help people understand how much TTL actually matters in this question.

That's basically why cache poisoning attacks work...

@LPChip But it's still independent of whether the cached entry is shared by all the clients of the router's DNS.

You are actually asking two questions here:

or only for each individual user?

There is nothing in the DNS protocol to identify specific users, so the DNS server can't cache data based on specific users.

Is a router's DNS cache shared among all users?

In a typical home router configuration, almost certainly the cache is shared.
However there are some uncommon options (read the server would have to be explicitly configured to do it) that allow a DNS server to provide different responses based on the interface the request came in on, the IP of the requesting client and possibly the authentication key provided by the client (cryptographically signed DNS).
TL;DR - Due to (ACL) filtering two clients may have different (active) configurations - one may enable caching and one may not, hence in this scenario the cache would not be shared between them.

Even if there was something in DNS which identified users, there's nothing that authenticates them either. Bob could simply pretend to be Alice.

@MSalters: In theory you can do client certificates with DoH, which would provide comprehensive bidirectional authentication (i.e. the server authenticates Alice and Alice authenticates the server). In practice, I've never heard of anyone implementing something like that. And it certainly can't be done with standard UDP DNS.

@Kevin - I didn't respond to MSalters because they are technically correct, it would be the client that is authenticated (read: the machine) not the user - I am not aware of anything in a current OS that allows DNS filtering down to a particular user of a machine, it is only the detail that different users are using different machines that means the cache may not be shared between them. Note: Authentication is also somewhat irrelevant here, DNS servers can be configured to filter responses based on IP address (of the client), which would have the same effect.

A DNS server caches DNS queries and any client that does a request for a DNS resolve on that DNS server will use the cache of the DNS server.
It doesn't matter where the DNS server is located. It can be on a Windows Server, or on your router. They'll work the same.
Do note, that when the DNS query is performed by the DNS server, it not only gets the ip address for that domain, but also the TTL value (or Time To Live).
This TTL value will basically tell the DNS server how long this result should be cached before it expires.
So even though Bob will first request the DNS and get the ipaddress cached, if that entry has only a TTL of 1 hour, and Alice requests that same domain 1,5 hours later, the TTL has expired and as such the DNS is first refreshed, and Alice may thus get a different ip address than Bob had, depending on how the DNS is configured.
Of course, if the cache entry has not yet expired, Alice will get that same IP address. A second request will of course not refresh the TTL value in the cache. So lets say Bob does a DNS request with TTL of 1 hour, Alice does that same request 45 minutes later, result is fetched from cache. Now Andrew does another request 30 minutes later, the entry TTL has been expired for 15 minutes, so a new internet request is performed by the DNS Server and a new entry is stored in the cache. It could be the same IP Address, but it can also be a different one.
It is possible that one domain has multiple A records with different IP addresses and short TTL values so Bob and Alice would get different IP addresses.

Thanks; this is a good answer. I forgot that yes, TTL might very well expire before another user can access that same domain. But I believe you have more or less said the same as the accepted answer, that if they are both using the cache then it will be shared?

Yes and no. The TTL value is not to be overlooked, and depending on why you ask this question, it may matter a lot, which is why I thought it would be mandatory to post an answer of my own. If the TTL value has indeed been expired because it was set to a low value on purpose with multiple A records, each user will most likely get a different IP address. If you hope that for a given situation they always get the same IP address, this answer tells you otherwise, while the first one doesn't.

the ttl is not relevant to the question in the title

Home router definitively cache DNS results, every client that use the router DNS use those values.
macOS: use scutil --dns and look for nameserver
Linux: use dnstracer or check /etc/resolv.conf
Windows: should be nslookup (check)
If the DNS is on your locar router you sharing the same cached values with other client.
This is the default setting on small home networks
